# Testing async redux action with call to browserHistory

Tags: testing, redux, react-router

I'm having an issue testing an async redux action (using thunk) that throws an error because `browserHistory` is undefined.

(code modified for brevity)

**actions.js**

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import axios from 'axios'

export function foo() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post('/foo')
      .then(res => { dispatch(something); browserHistory.push('/') })
      .catch(err => { dispatch(somethingError) }
  }
}
```

**test/actions.js**

```
import nock from 'nock'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])

describe('foo succeeds', () => {
  nock('localhost:300')
    .post('/foo')
    .reply(200)

  const store = mockStore()

  return store.dispatch(actions.foo())
    .then(expect(store.getActions()).to.equal(something))
})
```

This of course leads to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, which prompts an unhandled promise rejection. Is there any way I can mock out `browserHistory` or handle the error elegantly in the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be a simple fix. In your test file you can mock out react-router:

```
import * as router from 'react-router'

router.browserHistory = { push: () => {} }
```